# I don't understand this notation

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I`m having a homework question that goes like this: $X$ is a Hilbert space, a complete inner product space, show that $B(X)$ is not a Hilbert space.

My only question for now is what does $B(X)$ mean? My hunch is that that is the space of all bounded linear operators, and if I'm right please give a small example.

Comment: Writing $B(X)$ to denote " **B** ounded linear operators acting on $X$ " surely is common.

Answer (score 3):

@GiuseppeNegro is correct. Remember that a *linear* operator being bounded is equivalent to it being continuous so you could equivalently view $B(X)$ as the continuous linear operators instead. Furthermore, given two Banach spaces $Y,Z$, it is known that $B(Y,Z)$ is a Banach space. All Hilbert spaces are necessarily Banach spaces so your goal here is to show that while $B(X)$ is a Banach space, it is not a Hilbert space. You can find a hint for the problem in the spoiler text below.

> (If a Banach space satisfies the parallelogram law, it is a Hilbert space.)

Comment: Well i`m having another question: if $T \in B(X)$ then $T$ is a linear operator such that $T: X \rightarrow X$, it maps points from $X$ to itself again right?

Comment: Yes it maps points in $X$ to points in $X.$